# Why if(i) is taking more time than if(0 != i)

Tags: c

Why if(i) is taking more time than if(0 != i), please suggest which is a better way to check for arguments to a function.

Please find below code snippet:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct timeval  lBefore,lAfter,lResult;
    int i,j = 0;

    timerclear(&lBefore);
    timerclear(&lAfter);

    gettimeofday(&lBefore,NULL);

    for(i = 0; i < 0xFFFFFF; i++)
    {
        if(i)
        {
            j++;
        }
    }

    gettimeofday(&lAfter,NULL);

    timersub(&lAfter,&lBefore,&lResult);

    printf("[%d]%ld:%ld\n",j,lResult.tv_sec,lResult.tv_usec);

    j = 0;

    gettimeofday(&lBefore,NULL);

    for(i = 0; i < 0xFFFFFF; i++)
    {
        if(0 != i)
        {
            j++;
        }
    }

    gettimeofday(&lAfter,NULL);

    timersub(&lAfter,&lBefore,&lResult);

    printf("[%d]%ld:%ld\n",j,lResult.tv_sec,lResult.tv_usec);

    return 0;
}
```

Code output:

```
sh-4.2$ main
```

> [16777214]0:79030
>   [16777214]0:55605
>   sh-4.2$ main
>   [16777214]0:76910
>   [16777214]0:53657
>   sh-4.2$ main
>   [16777214]0:74696
>   [16777214]0:51295

Comment: did you enable optimization? did you check the generated assembly?

Comment: I believe this is compiler dependant and of course, platform too.

Comment: 1.) measure two otherwise **identical** programs for something reliable 2.) enable compiler optimizations.

Comment: GCC version used: 4.8.5 20150623

Comment: Yes compiled with both optimization flag enabled/disabled still results are pretty much same

Comment: Please mention reasons in comment for downvoting

Comment: Can you show us *how* you build it? And have you compared the generated (assembly) code of the two loops (with optimizations enabled)?

Comment: Your method is flawed. Doing the same thing **twice** will probably benefit from e.g. cache. Use two separate programs. And then, this test case is silly, a good optimizing compiler could decide not to emit a loop *at all*.

Comment: Used online compiler link: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php, updated built command as gcc -O3 -Wall -o main *.c

Comment: Change the order of the tests and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

It is not the truth. The code is exactly the same. Have checked with 4 popular compilers:

examples gcc x86-64

-O0

```
if(i)
    cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
    je      .L3

if(0 != i)
    cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
    je      .L7
```

-O3

```
if(i) ....
    test    rax, rax
    lea     ebx, [rdx+1]
    jne     .L13
    mov     ebx, edx
    jmp     .L3

if(0 != i) ...
    test    rax, rax
    lea     ebx, [rdx+1]
    jne     .L15
    mov     ebx, edx
    jmp     .L6
```

PS I hate this ridiculous form `0 != i` instead of `i != 0`

PS2 maybe somewhere in the universe exist C compilers generating different code for those conditions but `i` is an exact equivalent of `i != 0` so it quite difficult to imagine, but everything is possible.

Comment: please can you share the result as well as the compilers used.

Comment: While you should add a "*most likely*" or something (you **could** find a compiler generating different code from these inputs), it's still a good answer.

Comment: You can do it yourself

Answer (score 0):

This is just wrong, but your method is flawed. You should make sure your program does only **one** of the tests at a time and you should make sure that the loop **needs** to execute. Here's a modified version that corrects these methodic issues:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int test1(void)
{
    int j = 0;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 0xFFFFFF; i++)
    {
        int x = rand();
        if(x)
        {
            j++;
        }
    }
    return j;
}

int test2(void)
{
    int j = 0;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 0xFFFFFF; i++)
    {
        int x = rand();
        if(0 != x)
        {
            j++;
        }
    }
    return j;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int which = 0;
    if (argc>1) which = atoi(argv[1]);
    srand(1);

    struct timeval lBefore,lAfter,lResult;

    timerclear(&lBefore);
    timerclear(&lAfter);
    gettimeofday(&lBefore,NULL);

    int j = which ? test2() : test1();

    gettimeofday(&lAfter,NULL);
    timersub(&lAfter,&lBefore,&lResult);
    printf("[%d]%ld:%ld\n",j,lResult.tv_sec,lResult.tv_usec);   
}
```

Results on the website you linked:

```
sh-4.2$ main 0
[16777215]0:199145
sh-4.2$ main 0
[16777215]0:211709
sh-4.2$ main 0
[16777215]0:193211
sh-4.2$ main 0
[16777215]0:184544
sh-4.2$ main 0
[16777215]0:196465
sh-4.2$ main 1
[16777215]0:202904
sh-4.2$ main 1
[16777215]0:206235
sh-4.2$ main 1
[16777215]0:183214
sh-4.2$ main 1
[16777215]0:203317
sh-4.2$ main 1
[16777215]0:207389
```

So you see there's no difference at all.